# Rewrite Folder Path htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How would I achieve this rewrite through htaccess?

From `http://example.com/data/user/variable.png`

To `http://example.com/user/variable.png`

Comment: the user directory is also a variable that depends on the URL

Comment: There are so many examples for such rewritings to be found in the documentation, here and on google or where ever. Did you try some and why did they not satisfy you?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Make use of Apache Module [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).
Create or edit an .htaccess file in your project folder.
Enable Apache Module mod_rewrite within this folder.
Set a rewrite rule.
Optional: Relocate to existing files.

## Steps

Enable the rewrite module:

```
# make use of Apache Module mod_rewrite (must be installed and enabled)
RewriteEngine On
```

... add a redirect rule, like this:

```
# redirect all requests matching "./data/*" to "./*"
RewriteRule ^data/(.*) $1
```

... and you are done.
The browser URL will remain, but content will be delivered from the rewritten resource.

If the target resource is existing as file, add the redirect-flag:

```
# relocate all requests matching "./data/*" to "./*"
RewriteRule ^data/(.*) $1 [R]
```

This will redirect the browser to the new resource.